# C# Override virtual function without having to implement another class

Tags: c#, class, overriding, virtual, inheritance

I am trying to override a virtual function only for a single defined element (without having to create another class that implements it and then adding a function to override it..).

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual bool ChangeStatus(String status)
    {
        return false;
    }
}


void test()
{
    //The following is written as an example of what I am trying to achieve & does not work
    MyClass blah = new MyClass()
    {
        public override bool ChangeStatus(String status)
        {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont get why you are overriding same function for same class, overriding gives new meaning to the same signatured function where the class is inherited depending on requirement

Comment: @brykneval: It is for an API, the "void test()" part will be used into different assemblies. Does that clear it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have control over `MyClass`, you can let the desired method call a delegate which can be replaced for every single object at runtime...

```
class MyClass
{
    public void Func<SomeParameterType,SomeReturnType> myDelegate {get;set;}
    public SomeReturnType myFunction(SomeParameterType parameter)
    {
        if(myDelegate==null)
            throw new Exception();
        return myDelegate(parameter);
    }
}

...

MyClass obj = new MyClass();
SomeParameterType p = new SomeParameterType();
obj.myDelegate = (x)=>new SomeReturnType(x);
SomeReturnType result = obj.myFunction(p);
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I am looking for, even thought, it wasn't what I directly asked. I will try this whenever I have time to. Edit: Sadly, I don't have enough reputation to "Up" your answer.

Comment: @bash.d: I am using this for an API... I don't know if that answers your question...does it?

Comment: No, not really... I believe you should dig up some books on OOP and see what inheritance is about...

Comment: @bash.d the delegate type definition would most probably belong in the namespace ... since i used Func<T,S> here i omitted that ... the Property where the delegate is stored is an instance member for a reason: you can replace the actual method implementation per object ... make it static, and you have per class ... if you want this effect (and even more options) with pure oop, you would have to implement the interceptor pattern ... but sometimes this is already sufficient to achive the desired effect

Answer (score 1):

"virtual" and "override" both are related to INHERITANCE.

1.[A virtual method can be redefined. The virtual keyword designates a method that is overridden in derived classes. We can add derived types without modifying the rest of the program. The runtime type of objects thus determines behavior.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/virtual)

2.[When you want to allow a derived class to override a method of the base class, within the base class method must be created as virtual method and within the derived class method must be created using the keyword override.](http://www.programcall.com/26/csnet/virtual-methods-in-csnet-with-example.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

C# is strictly built on the concept of classes. You cannot create a function/method without a class.
Additionally, `virtual/override` implies inheritance, so you MUST derive from this class.

Comment: that is not entirely true ... you can have a function/method without a class around it ... think of delegates

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question... This is about overriding not creating delegates or stuff!

Comment: sure thing ... op stated he is **trying** to override ... that doesn't work ... then he asks for **any** idea on how to achive the effect ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: Yep pretty much what I wanted > _alternatives_

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `override` a function without `inheriting the class`, the whole point of a `virtual function` is that it can be `overridden` in the `child class`.

If your are doing it withing the same class, wouldn't you end up writing a simple method/function for the class ?

So, **follow the OOP programming concept, it is designed for simplicity & ease of programming**. `Instead simply inherit the class and override the function`

Comment: Actually, they aren't in the class. The snippet I wrote in my original post does not have any context neither is it included in a namespace or a parent class, it is just to show off what I am trying to achieve.